# How to get the values of few input fields in java script and write them on web?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, input, onclick

I would like to take all values from all input fields and write them on the web.

Here is my code:

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {

  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input").value;
  for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i];
  }

  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.innerHTML = "To sa: " + inputs;
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
</div>


<button>Check</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `document.querySelectorAll("input").value;` does not give you the joined values of all selected inputs.

Instead, you could append the values to a new variable inside the `for` loop, through something like:

```
inputsAppended += inputs[i].value;
```

Finally, you can output it using:

```
output.innerHTML = "To sa: " + inputsAppended;
```

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var inputsAppended = "";
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputsAppended += inputs[i].value;
  }

  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.innerHTML = "To sa: " + inputsAppended;
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
</div>


<button>Check</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I only wonder why I cannot use .value straight in inputs variable at the end, but only inside for loop after inputs[i]?

Comment: @Blosom That's because value is a property of individual input, whereas inputs is a collection of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {

  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  
  output.innerHTML += inputs[i].value;
  }

  
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
</div>


<button>Check</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach where all numbers are printed in different lines

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  //iterate all inputs, get their values, and join them separated by a line break
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
 [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input")).map( s => s.value ).join( "<br>" );
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="49">
</div>


<button>Check</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```